# Remove all spaces in column data for entire table

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

below is my simple action, im trying to remove all the spaces in the machinenames, i thought the below would of done it, but it doesnt do anything, data stays the same :|
anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

```
            var Equipment = db.tblEquipments;
            foreach (var Item in Equipment)
            {
                Item.MachineName.Replace(" ", "");
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are immutable in c#, so [`Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) does not change the original string, it produces instead a whole new string. You need to assign the result back to the original value in order to actually change it:

```
var Equipment = db.tblEquipments;
foreach (var Item in Equipment)
{
  //actually set the changed value to the original
  Item.MachineName = Item.MachineName.Replace(" ", "");
}
db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something like that:

```
var Equipment = db.tblEquipments;
foreach (var Item in Equipment)
{
    Item.MachineName = Item.MachineName.Replace(" ", "");
}
db.SaveChanges();
```